# Apache - Invalid command 'SSLMutex'

Tags: apache, mod-ssl

I am in the process of upgrading Apache version from 2.0 to 2.4. After 2.4 installed, I have faced below issue.

```
Invalid command 'SSLMutex', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
AH00526: Syntax error on line 77 of /apache/conf/ssl.conf:
```

The line #77 in ssl.conf is `SSLMutex  file:/apache/logs/ssl_mutex`.

I have loaded mod_ssl and along with I have loaded below mod also but still I could not fix this.

```
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
```

NOTE: If I comment out the SSLMutex line in ssl.conf file then Apache is working including SSL port. I am afraid what will happen if SSLMutex issue is not resolved. Please suggest some solution.

thanks

Answer (score 74):

Replace SSLMutex with

```
Mutex default
```

The SSLMutex has been Dropped after 2.2

Comment: Is it correct directive "Mutex sysvsem default", not "Mutex default sysvsem"? When I use first option I obtain error on Apache run. When I run second option Apache runs fine. I found suggestion at http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,119090,119180 . At the same time Apache doc http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html is not clear how exactly to eliminate `SSLMutex`, it just states that SSLMutex should be eliminated

Comment: Only **Mutex default** is working for me on Apache 2.4.9

Comment: Can someone update this answer to the correct syntax please?

Comment: I have Apache 2.2.6 on Windows 10 and for me the only thing that worked was to write the line "SSLMutex default" in the httpd-ssl.conf file. "Mutex default" ended up with an unknown directive error when trying to start my local Apache 2 server.

Comment: this is odd, because i got this from my rpnnew.  maybe that was from a former upgrade.  ugh. then weres the new rpmnew?

Answer (score 11):

Unless you had some specific mutex configuration on your 2.2, just commenting out this line will prompt Apache to use the default mutex mechanism.
See the documentation for [upgrading 2.2 to 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html) and the [mutex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#mutex) directive documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the equivalent Apache SSL config use:

```
Mutex file:/apache/logs/ssl_mutex
```

The ssl_mutex is a directory on a drive local to the server, accessible by Apache (httpd process), not in a global readable directory (e.g. not in '/tmp') and not on a network storage (e.g. not NFS).

Reference:
[Apache Core Features](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html)

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

changed from config for Apache 2.2:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf:

SSLMutex  file:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl_mutex
```

to Apache 2.4

to

```
Mutex  file:${APACHE_RUN_DIR} default
```