# Wamp: getting a "Configuration Failed" error

Tags: wamp

So i'm trying to setup my Wamp 64-bit (win10 latest) and specifically a instance of a local project to run on ssl. Problem is i've fiddled with the configuration files, generated and added the crt/key files and all that but the issue is that i'm only getting the error message from the title, nothing else.

No other warning/notices/error to be found anywhere. I've looked in the Microsoft event viewer, php error logs, nothing.

My question is how do i find out what's wrong if there are no logs apart from the one in the title?

---

Think this was my fiddling process:
Uncomment from `httpd.conf` the following lines:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
```

Generate cert and key via command `openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.crt` then put the files into `c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.39/conf/key`
Modify my `vhost` file to look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:\users\USRENAME\sites\devdesktop\lsecurities-dev\docroot"
    ServerName local.project1
    ServerAlias local.project1

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.39/conf/key/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.39/conf/key/server.key"

    ErrorLog "c:/users/USRENAME/sites/devdesktop/lsecurities-dev/error.log"

    <Directory  "c:/users/USRENAME/sites/devdesktop/lsecurities-dev/docroot">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

**UPDATE:**
I finally managed to get some errors:

```
[Fri Jun 19 15:55:49.666142 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 8460:tid 700] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for www.example.com:443
[Fri Jun 19 15:55:49.666142 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 8460:tid 700] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
```

**UPDATE 2** [solved] found what i was looking for in this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/39585222/2985565

Answer (score 0):

This was the missing piece: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39585222/2985565
Forgot to add the crt/key file in the `http-ssl`